# Getting a value from a session in Grails

Tags: grails

```
def u = new User(params)
session.user = u
```

Above is the code i'm using to set a session in grails, however when i use the following code to get a value from the session later on, it returns null for the value.

```
session.getAttribute('username')
```

I understand that getAttribute returns null if the Attribute doesn't exist, so is there another way of getting the username from the session?

Comment: Emm, dude! You are setting "user", but trying to get the "username"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `user` into session, but read `username`. Actually, you can read the value from session even easier, without using `getAttribute()`. I've just tried with Grails 3.2.4 this code:

```
session.someValue = 'Hello World!'
println "session.someValue = $session.someValue"
```

and the output is:

```
session.someValue = Hello World!
```

So, in your case you can do:

```
def u = new User(params)
session.user = u // write to session
def userFromSession = session.user // read from session
```